# Resharper not detecting rename o variable

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

I have visual studio 2015 and resharper ultimate.

Resharper is not detecting when I rename a variable, and so, is not letting me to rename all references to that variable.

Any ideias?

Comment: You're renaming with `CTRL-R,R`?

Comment: no, i just go to variable and rename it. inline.